# Using the ${} in Java annotations should allow to use properties values... but it is not working every time?

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi

I have a simple Java Spring Boot application that uses springdoc openAPI v2 here is part of the maven file I am using ( I will spare you the rest of the details it is just starter web to be able to have a rest controller nothing fancy and especially nothing relevant here):

I use the spring boot starter parent for my application

```xml
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
  <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

Then I have the following for Spring Doc OpenAPI:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${springdoc.openapi.starter.webmvc.version}</version> // this is defined as 2.0.2 in properties file
</dependency>
```

I define now an @OpenApiConfiguration as such (note: here values are BS and always the same, they all point to a value defined in my application.yaml, it is just to test everything before pushing more code, the idea being to define the API in the properties file):

```java
@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(
        info = @Info(title = "${openapi.info.name}", contact = @Contact(name = "${openapi.info.name}")),
        tags = {
                @Tag(name = "${openapi.info.name}"),
        },
        extensions = @Extension(properties = {
                @ExtensionProperty(name = "${openapi.info.name}", value = "${openapi.info.name}"),
        })
)
```

Doing the above declaration I can now check my generated JSON OpenAPI contract expecting every value to be replaces but to my surprise only few of the values were replaced:

```json
{
"openapi":"3.0.1",
"info":{
  "title":"ttt", //replaced correctly
  "contact":{
    "name":"ttt" //replaced correctly
  }
},
"servers":[
  {
    "url":"http://localhost:8080/api-2023",
    "description":"Generated server url"
  }
],
"tags":[
  {
    "name": "${openapi.info.name}" // not replaced
  }
],
"x-${openapi.info.name}":"${openapi.info.name}"} // not replaced
```

I really do not understand much about how the substitution occurs and why it doesn't my understanding is that whatever comes from the ${} nomenclature should be coming from application.yaml but apparently not. What I am really confused about is why sometimes it works and sometimes not. I would have imagined everything work or doesn't?

Can anyone shed a light on this please?

Comment: The use of `${...}` only works in Spring annotations, because Spring itself performs special postprocessing on those values. Likely in the case of those `@ExtensionProperty`, Spring provides no support.

Comment: And they retrieves their values from Spring's [application properties mechanism](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring), not from a random openapi spec file.